# Observable not working after angular update from angular 2.rc4 to final

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Since upgrading my app from angular 2.rc.4 and rxjs.beta.6 to angular 2 final and rxjs.beta.12 the following just doesn't work anymore. I don't get an error message and I can't find anything in the changelogs. I inserted some comments at the problematic code. All of this worked fine in rc.4

the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class StocksService {

  private _portfolio: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  private _transactions: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { 
    this._portfolio = BehaviorSubject.create();
  }

  get portfolio() {
    return this._portfolio.asObservable();
  }

  get transactions() {
    return this._transactions.asObservable();
  }

  loadPortfolio(): void {
    this.apiService.get('/depot')
    .map(res => res.json())
// the correct data is in res.data here, but it doesn't get to the component
    .subscribe(res => this._portfolio.next(res.data));
  }

  loadTransactions(): void {
    this.apiService.get('/transactions')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => this._transactions.next(res.data));
  }

  search(id: string) {
    return this.apiService.get('/stocks/search')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

and the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { StocksService } from './stocks.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'tradity-portfolio',
  templateUrl: 'app/portfolio.component.html',
  providers: [StocksService]
})
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {

  portfolio: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private stocksService: StocksService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.portfolio = this.stocksService.portfolio;
// the following console.log doesn't fire like it used to in rc.4
    this.portfolio.subscribe(val => console.log("received", val));
    this.stocksService.loadPortfolio();
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, I guess the problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. The mistake was in the service's constructor.

```
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { 
    this._portfolio = BehaviorSubject.create();
}
```

should have been

```
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { 
    this._portfolio = new BehaviorSubject("");
}
```